# Cognitive face API Python 2.7.x - Bad Image Url

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, urllib3

Trying to run the following program to post the faces stored in a folder using ImageUrl but there exists an error.
The API I used is MS's Cognitive Face API v1.0
Please help

```
import sys
import os, time
import cognitive_face as CF
from global_variables import personGroupId
import urllib
import sqlite3

Key = '---some key----'  #I removed the key her for some security Purpose
CF.Key.set(Key)

def get_person_id():
    person_id = ''
    extractId = str(sys.argv[1])[-2:]
    connect = sqlite3.connect("Face-DataBase")
    c = connect.cursor()
    cmd = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = " + extractId
    c.execute(cmd)
    row = c.fetchone()
    person_id = row[3]
    connect.close()
    return person_id

if len(sys.argv) is not 1:
    currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    imageFolder = os.path.join(currentDir, "dataset/" + str(sys.argv[1]))
    person_id = get_person_id()
    for filename in os.listdir(imageFolder):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            print(filename)
            imgurl = urllib.request.pathname2url(os.path.join(imageFolder, filename))
            res = CF.face.detect(imgurl)
            if len(res) != 1:
                print ("No face detected in image")
            else:
                res = CF.person.add_face(imgurl, personGroupId, person_id)
                print(res)  
            time.sleep(6)
```

The error I got is a Invalid Image Url with Status Code '400'

```
 User.22.1.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_person_faces.py", line 31, in <module>
    res = CF.face.detect(imgurl)
  File "C:\Users\Avina\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\cognitive_face\face.py", line 41, in detect
    data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Avina\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\cognitive_face\util.py", line 102, in request
    error_msg.get('message'))
cognitive_face.util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:
        status_code: 400
        code: InvalidURL
        message: Invalid image URL.
```

Comment: You're trying to send a path to a local image as a URL?

Comment: Yes, he wants to add this for a local file. I am facing the same issue. Do anyone have an answer to this error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to send a public url or send the image in binary format for the API to be able to access it.

Here is how you read the image:

```
try: 
   with open('mypic.jpg', 'rb') as image:
       img = image.read()
       face_to_detect = bytearray(img)
       print("image reading done!")

except Exception as ex:
    print("exception in reading image bytes {0}".format(ex.args))
    has_exception = True
```

And then post it:

```
 result = cf.face.detect(face_to_detect)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate and explain how to write code for that

Comment: There is an error generated while running the code with modifications given by you.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Just checked the CF SDK doesn't accept bytesarray. I got the same error that you're getting when I used your code. The issue is with the call to urllib.request.pathname2url which translates it to a format that the SDK is unable to parse. 

Just remove the call to pathname2url and this should work.